Export number fields without quotation marks on SQL Developer
I am using Oracle SQL Developer 20.2.0.175.
I have the table X with a numeric and a VARCHAR column.
X_IDIOMA     NUMBER(2) NOT NULL 
X_DESC_CORTA VARCHAR2(6 CHAR)

I do select * from x;. Then, I export the results to clipboard.

The problem is, I get the X_IDIOMA column that is a number, exported with quotation marks.
INSERT INTO X (X_IDIOMA, X_DESC_CORTA) VALUES ('1', 'FRIES');

I would like to export the numeric column without quotation marks, like this:
INSERT INTO X (X_IDIOMA, X_DESC_CORTA) VALUES (1, 'FRIES');

I have been researching, and I can't find the option I should modify on the settings, so quotation marks are no added to the number columns when exporting a table.
I have been looking at the settings:

What option should I modify so number columns are exported as a numbers, without quotation marks?
Using a different version of SQL Developer would be hard since I can't add any software.

Why have you tagged SQL server? It's totally different to oracle

We dont quote numbers, please share your table definitions.
